# Multiple records concatenated in one query string

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a table dynamically generated from my database with PHP (which was a victory for me in and of itself). The user can enter changes to as many fields and records as she wants

On hitting submit, the updated records should update in the database. I could probably get away with updating *all* records, even ones which haven't changed, but that's kinda lame. I've gotten up to serializing the data string, which looks something like:

> category=Phone&error_level=1&service_name=API&status=Critical&notes=None&category=Phone&error_level=1&service_name=Inbound+Calls&status=Critical&notes=None&category=Phone&error_level=2&service_name=Outbound+Calls&status=Minor+issue&notes=None&category=Consumer&error_level=1&service_name=www.website1.com&status=Critical&notes=None&category=Consumer&error_level=…

However, I have no idea how to proceed; i.e. I don't know what to do with this query string.  It now contains all the values from all of the rows. How do I break this up into the records, and how do I go about updating them in the database?

I considered splitting them into rows with a regex, then iterating over the list... but that seems hacky to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Split by `&`. Then loop over the pairs. Split them each by `=`, and put them in a map. Why is that hacky?

Comment: Just because I'm still learning and I don't want to do something over-involved when a better solution already exists.

Comment: (i.e., use a regex when there is an explode function, which I didn't know about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the same parameter name multiple times if you want to get all the values. You will only get one value in this case.

What you likely need to do is use array access notation in your input field names.

I am assuming you have some sort of integer id for each row so that you know the row's id in the database and can relate that back.  If that is the case you can have you input like this:

(Note: for simplicity sake I am showing inputs within a table since you mentioned you have a table)

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="some_column_name[1]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="another_column_name[1]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="third_column_name[1]" ... /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="some_column_name[2]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="another_column_name[2]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="third_column_name[2]" ... /></td>
</tr>
```

Note how the value in brackets for each `name` property would be the integer id for the row.

Now when you POST this data, PHP will assemble arrays in `$_POST` like this:

```
var_dump($_POST['some_column_name']);
var_dump($_POST['another_column_name']);
var_dump($_POST['third_column_name']);
```

Would output:

```
Array([1] => 'some value', [2] => 'some other value');
Array([1] => 'some value 2', [2] => 'some other value 2');
Array([1] => 'some value 3', [2] => 'some other value 3');
```

If you wanted all the POSTed values in a single multi-dimensional array, you might even consider doing something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="table_data[1][some_column_name]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="table_data[1][another_column_name]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="table_data[1][third_column_name]" ... /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="table_data[2][some_column_name]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="table_data[2][another_column_name]" ... /></td>
    <td><input name="table_data[2][third_column_name]" ... /></td>
</tr>
```

Which, when POSTed, would give you an array like

```
Array
([1] => Array(
    ['some_column_name'] => 'value',
    ['another_column_name'] => 'value',
    ['third_column_name'] => 'value'
    ),
 [2] => Array(
    ['some_column_name'] => 'value',
    ['another_column_name'] => 'value',
    ['third_column_name'] => 'value'
    )
)
```

You might find this easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Explode your data string using "&" as a delimiter. Loop through the resulting array and explode each item using "=" as a delimiter.

But you can't send the string like that without encoding it, or PHP will split it at the "&" characters before you can, creating a mess, probably. Or you could get the raw post data and try it with that string.

It might be easier just to send the whole form, really.

Comment: Explode sounds promising (I just learned it existed).  I'm going to investigate, but first:

I thought this _was_ the raw post data.  I got it from $(form).serialize().  Am I in error?

Comment: There are a couple ways to get post data in PHP. Usually, you'll use the $_POST array. That works with forms and AJAX post data that is formatted like your string. If you are sending it along as a form value, then it will be something like `val=blah.....` where blah is the string you posted above. And then you'd find it in $_POST['val']. Or you can get it as one big chunk in `php://input` and parse it as I suggested.

Comment: Are you sending this by AJAX? That simplifies things. But do take care of the other problems mentioned by others, first.

Comment: Ah. Then you can send a string that that in your data parameter, and everything should be available in `$_POST`. But you'll need to differentiate your variables somehow. Formatting your data like `category[]=Phone` (and so on) will work. Then you'll have an array of arrays and will need to access your data like this: `$_POST['category'][0]` and so on. The use of the empty brackets [] autoincrements the index. VERY helpful in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

make yourself familiar with arrays and [JSON](http://json.org).

JSON will help you to serialize an array from javascript to PHP. In PHP, you can iterate through the (PHP) array then and process the records of the array and insert / update to your database as you want.

You must not do that manually up to the end as you have started above but leave that up to the build in functionality of JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Right now that looks something like this

```
category=Phone
error_level=1
service_name=API
status=Critical
notes=None

category=Phone
error_level=1
service_name=Inbound+Calls
status=Critical
notes=None

category=Phone
error_level=2
service_name=Outbound+Calls
status=Minor+issue
notes=None

category=Consumer
error_level=1
service_name=www.website1.com
status=Critical
notes=None
```

Currently, there is no way to distinguish one record from another so you aren't able to run an if statement to check to see if that record has been updated. If you could add another input field (even if it was hidden) that included the row's unique ID you could run an If statement to check to see if the records have changed then run a MySQL Update statement on that row.

Without something Unique to check to see if it has been updated I would just delete all of the rows and read them with an Insert statement for each row.